# Using DX Auth for Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

Has anyone used DX Auth for Codeigniter bundeled examples?

After following Installing DX Auth library with bundled examples on http://dexcell.shinsengumiteam.com/dx_auth/installation/index.html

I added a route $route['auth'] = "auth"; in config/routes.php, uploaded /controllers/auth.php, added $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc', 'DX_Auth'); in /config/autoload.php.

The bundled example comes with the views in a subfolder /views/auth.
I tried to put the register_form.php view in both /views and /views/auth.

Once I enter http://mydomain.com/auth/register I get a blank page, like no view is loading.
An help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've considered using DX Auth for a while, but I ended up using Redux Auth instead for flexibility and simplicity.

Redux is outdated now, but the new [Ion Auth](http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) is based on Redux Auth, and works great for me.

They have good documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

What does your PHP error log say?

Also, this is kind of a tangent but you might want to check out Tank_auth, which was built on DX_Auth and contains a # of security updates/fixes.

http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/

Comment: hi pigfox, if u've found your solution please mark this as solved or "accept" my solution.  thanks!